# Which system call is used by sleep() in Windows?

Tags: windows, sleep, system-calls

I am trying to understand how the sleep() function works in Windows.

Does anyone know which system call is actually used when the sleep() function is executed in Windows machines? If possible, I would need to know the precise system call used in Windows 7 32bit.

Thanks

Comment: Which `sleep()` are you referring to? Different libraries likely use different implementations.

Comment: @IInspectable Sorry, you are right, well I believe the most common one is the one in Windows.h https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx
So at least that one :)

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You ask for a very specific implementation detail, and then decide, that you do not even care about a particular implementation, but want to know for a common (by some definition of *"most common"*) implementation. What problem are you really trying to solve here?

Comment: @IInspectable I am trying to understand what is the base system call used by the windows OS to implement the sleep mechanism. It does not sound to me like a strange question at all...
Since you are right and different sleep functions may use different implementations, I can live with just finding out what is the implementation of the one function inside the standard Windows.h library.

Comment: Not that I believe that it's very helpful, but `Sleep` calls `SleepEx`, which in turn calls `NtDelayExecution`. That's syscall 0x31 (on Windows 7 x64). If you really need to know, what index it is on 32-bit versions of Windows 7, check it for yourself.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks that is pretty much what I wanted to know